# The dimension orders of the Numpy 3D array are designed to z, x, y. Are there any advantages?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, 3d

I think that the x,y,z order is more intuitive for a 3D array, just as Matlab does. For example, If someone tells me an array is 2x3x4, I will think it is 2 rows, 3 columns, 4 frames, instead of 2 frames, 3 rows, 4 columns.

Is there any core reason why the creators of NumPy had to do this？

Comment: This is often described as Fortran column major versus C row major.

Comment: MATLAB was created as a interpreted front end to a bunch of Fortran linear algebra functions.  Everything was 2d with the normal Fortran order.  Extension to 3d (and more) was a later addition.  `numpy` runs in Python.  The default input and display of numpy arrays mirrors the nesting of lists.  Arrays can also have 0,1, or more dimensions.  With `strides` it is possible to "order" the dimensions in any way.  Our "intuitions" are strongly influenced by what we frequently use.

Comment: Consider a typical image with (460,800,3) size/shape, commonly labeled as (high,wide,channels).  Does it make more sense to think of the 'channels' as separate "pages",a red page, a green one etc.  or does a pixel (selected on the first 2 dimenesions) have 3 colors?  How does a C++ based package like `cv2` store it?  Or any of the other image formats?

Answer (score 0):

@hpaulj You mentioned that the default input of the Numpy array is the nesting of lists. It inspires me.

For a nesting list,

```
l=[
    [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
    [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
]

len(l)  # 2
len(l[0])  # 3
len(l[0][0]) # 4
```

its order of the length keeps consistency with the shape of the Numpy array.

```
np.array(l).shape  # (2, 3, 4)
```

Maybe that is the reason.